# http -> https has caused issues with a specific challenge

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hyperlinks

Take a look at this challenge: [Print This Question ↓](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55857/68942)

It asks to print the exact contents of the question. Cool, right? There's even a [comment by ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55857/print-this-question-%E2%86%93/55991#comment135683_55857) saying "*Let this be a reminder not to edit this post. Ever. Or we're all screwed.*"

However, Community edited the `http` link in there to become `https`. This is necessary for the `https` transition; however, it makes it look like all of the answers are invalidated (see below). Should this be kept this way or rolled back?

Note that the challenge's specifications point to a specific revision, which means that the answers appear invalid but if you look carefully are actually good according to the original specs.

Also note that none of the answers have been active for less than half a year and...

wait Mr. Xcoder just rolled back the Community edits.

So as a general question, should the https revisions be kept (invalidating some answers) or rolled back (potentially causing link rot) for really old challenges?

Comment: Note that the same type of thing invalidated bots in Helka Homba's [Red vs Blue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48353/65836)

Comment: In addition to invalidating current answers, it also means any new answers will be effectively performing a new, slightly different task. Perhaps the original text should be added as a code block?

Comment: @trichoplax it's already in a pastebin link in the original, so it's not too much of a problem.

Comment: Ah I see - that link goes to the source of the specific revision, not the source of the latest version. That's very handy.

Answer (score 10):

## Roll back

The https transition made by Community is, in this case, an edit you would reject as a suggested edit in review, since it drastically changes the meaning of the post, telling people to print something different than intended.

Comment: `...made by Community is, in this case, an edit you would reject...` Community is hurting the community. [tag:fire-community] ;)

Comment: @totallyhuman but you can't really reject it since that user has diamond

Comment: +1 SE has http->https redirection anyway. The only reason Community made the change was likely to save everyone a redirect (or maybe some weird part of the transition).

Comment: @Poke The redirection didn't always exist...

Comment: At the time of this metapost it sure did. That fits into the "weird part of the transition" bit of my comment

Comment: @Poke The edit by Community was made on [2017-04-13 12:39:07Z](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/55857/4). I'm pretty sure it didn't exist back then.

Comment: I didn't argue that it didn't ever exist